# Is any paging plugin dynamic html table with collapsed rows available?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, tablesorter

I am working with html tables with collapsed rows. meaning each row will have 2 or more hidden rows which display on click of a button.

I need a paging plugin to work on the visible rows only(paging by class name). Is there a plugin for that. I see that "Tablesorter mod" and Datatables work with only static tables.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a recommendation engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessairly a "paging" plugin. It is more of a behavioral plugin.
You can use [this example from datatables site](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html) that shows how to show hide details. Just spice it up with some jQuery to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Hey iro problem with this is the collapsible tables is generated from the visible row, in my case the collapsible rows are not generated on the fly from parent. Unless i am missing something here

Comment: You mean the detail rows are created dynamically based on some event *after* the initial datatables initialization?

Comment: if u look at the datatables example, when you click the expand button is merely takes the value from the visible row and builds a child row out of it. in my case I have a parent and child row already populated. So wondering if the same logic will work on my code as well.

Comment: You could use the `fnFormatDetails` function. Just copy the data from hidden rows (i think that's what you want) and place it in there, and delete the source row from the DOM so it doesn't show. At least that's what i think is possible.

Comment: ok will give it a go and update you...